# Exponential size comparison

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a function $y(x) $ that is supposed to be greater or equal than 0 for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ y(x) = \frac{\sqrt{(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1})^2 - (e^x + 1) (e^{-x^2}-1)} -(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1}) }{1+e^x} $$

I have shown that $\sqrt{(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1})^2 - (e^x + 1) (e^{-x^2}-1)}$ is always positive or 0, and $-(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1})$ is always negative or 0.
How can I show that the numerator is always positive? I have plotted it using wolframalpha.

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides to get the following equivalence: 
$$
\sqrt{(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1})^2 - (e^x + 1) (e^{-x^2}-1)} -(e^{x^2} - e^{2x-1}) \ge 0 \leftrightarrow (e^x + 1) (e^{-x^2}-1) \le 0,
$$
which is indeed true for $x \in \mathbf{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

As both sides are non-negative, you can square both sides of inequalities:
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&\sqrt{(\mathrm e^{x^2} - \mathrm e^{2x-1})^2 - (\mathrm e^x + 1) (\mathrm e^{-x^2}-1)} &> \mathrm e^{x^2} - \mathrm e^{2x-1} \\
\iff&&(\mathrm e^{x^2} - \mathrm e^{2x-1})^2 - (\mathrm e^x + 1) (\mathrm e^{-x^2}&-1)>(\mathrm e^{x^2} - \mathrm e^{2x-1})^2 \\
\iff&& - (\mathrm e^x + 1) (\mathrm e^{-x^2}-1)>0\iff\mathrm 1&-e^{-x^2}  > 0,
\end{alignat}
which is true for all $x\ne 0$.